# Why can't JQuery load my resource?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following script in an page called ajax.aspx page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var nameFoundMessage = $('#nameFoundMessage');
        var nameInput = $('#name');

        nameFoundMessage.hide();

        nameInput.blur(function () {


            if ($(this).val()) {


                $.getJSON('Services/ArtistFound.aspx?' + escape($(this).val()), function (results) {

                    if (results.available) {
                        if (nameFoundMessage.is(':visible')) {
                            nameFoundMessage.html('The name was found');
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        nameFoundMessage.show();
                        nameFoundMessage.html('The name was not found');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The page has an input field with an id of "name" and when I blur off of that it goes into a service folder which has another aspx page ArtistFound.aspx and in that Page load, I have the following:

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        string name = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        string output = string.Empty;

        name = db.Names.Single(x => x.Name== name).Name;

        if(name == null)
        {
            output = "{available:false}";
        }
        else
        {
            output = "{available:true}";
        }

        Response.Write(output);
}
```

When I run the page and blur off the input, it says the following:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have tried ../Services/ArtistFound.aspx... and /Services/ArtistFound.aspx..., but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: The error is somewhere in the code in the ArtistFound.aspx page, and not jQuery. try loading the page directly and debugging the page. jQuery is just passing through the error.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in ArtistFound.aspx, is it getting loaded at all? Since that's not a WebService, but just a page, the format of the querystring shouldn't break it - it sounds like the code of that page is not working.

Comment: You are right, I am using this statement to return get a name, but it is saying more sequence contains more than one element, but I just want to get a distinct name or ignore spaces, but I am not sure how to do it:   name = db.Names.Single(x => x.Name == name).Name;

Comment: `Names.First` if there are dups, and you don't care about them. Single requires there to be only a single match.

Comment: Names.First throws an exception when no elements are found. If I do FirstOrDefault, it throws a NullReference Exception instead of just assigning null to name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
    name = db.Names.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name== name);

    if(name != null && name.Name != null)
    {
        output = "{available:true}";
    }
    else 
    {
        output = "{available:false}";
    }
```

This will return null if it is not found rather than throwing an exception like Single() does.

I would also recommend you use an ASHX handler rather than an ASPX page to do this call. 
To do this you just add a 'Generic Handler' file in visual studio then you can put replace the ProcessRequest method with this:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string name = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
        string output = string.Empty;

        name = db.Names.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

        if (name != null && name.Name != null)
        {
            output = "{available:true}";
        }
        else
        {
            output = "{available:false}";
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(output);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know this is not the proper way, I was just following a tutorial on the 4 guys from rolla site, but using an ASHX handler info would be helpful.  On the current problem, if I use First, and it does not find anything, it throws an exception saying the no elements were found.  If I use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault, it throws the exception "NullReferenceException".  It doesn't return null which is what I want it to do.

Comment: For now, I just put it in a try catch block and I assign it null if it has throws the exception, but my span is not being set with the appropriate message.  Is there something wrong with my jquery code.  All I have on the aspx page is  Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> <span id="nameFoundMessage"></span>

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the .Name on the end. I have updated the code and it should work fine now without a try-catch.

Comment: That took care of the exception and removing the try-catch, but my span's html is not being set and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is there any javascript error? When you debug does the results object contain anything. Also, if you are finding a name it won't set the html of the span because of the visible check as you hide it at the beginning. Could you post up the html for that section as well?

Comment: I put a console.log(1) after the if($(this).val()) and it shows up in the console, however, I also put a console.log(2) after $.getJSON call and it is not being shown up n the console.  I do not see any javascript errors and because it doesn't go into the getJSON method, I can't see if results has anything.  The only other html I have above the script is the script pointing to the jquery source from googles cdn

Comment: You might want to run [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what is being returned from the getJSON call as it's not making it into the callback code for some reason.

Comment: I created the handler and added the code in ProcessRequest and I put Services/GetName.ashx... but it responds with 404 error.  Is there anything else I need to do to get my handler working.